# Submit / Reset Buttons - Order in the Form

Tags: forms, user-interface, usability

When it comes to putting the **submit and reset buttons** on your forms, **what order do you use?**

```
[SUBMIT] [RESET]
```

or

```
[RESET] [SUBMIT]
```

This issue has come up countless times at work...

So, in your opinion, which is the most usable for online users?

I personally favor the latter, but some people tend to think otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to the suggestions given already, I would like to add that the submit button should be an actual button where as reset or cancel just a link making it different from the submit button hence highlighting the fact that they are functionally different and keeping it simple. Last thing you want is to make your users think.

Comment: I agree with you completely on this one...
The last thing we need is to make users think.

Comment: You should be doing what everybody else is doing on your OS.  If you start trying to smarten up your design you're only going to make your application harder to use.

Comment: @Will: this being tagged "web-development" there is no reference OS. And if we assume this was a desktop app question, you would be better off consulting your operating system's UI guidelines and not other applications.

Comment: @nnevala that tag appeared a month after I made the comment.  My snark "what everybody else is doing" *tends* to mean following UI guidelines, as the majority of UI *tends* to follow these guidelines. I do agree you should follow your OS' UI guidelines.  Unless you're Sun, in which case you make your UI look as awful as possible.

Answer (score 8):

I might be in the minority here, but I **never** put a RESET button on my forms.

Besides when I'm testing the form, I can't see a situation where a user would need to delete *all* the data on the form.

And it's just too easy for a user to click it and wipe out all their hard work.

User benefit: Low

User potential problems: High

Comment: That works for me too, unless the page is already the result of a POST, whose headers then get resent. Or you get a browser warning. Like I said, I really can't see a scenario where a user would need to delete everything that they've just put into the form.

Comment: +1, If the user feels like they screw up and need to re start his work, they are mostly like to hit Close, Cancel, Back, Refresh and start over than using the reset button.

Answer (score 2):

I always use [Submit][Reset] like in most ms windows windwos [ok][cancel] :)

Answer (score 1):

The common format for dialogs in Windows is to have the cancel buttons on the far right (or should I say outside?).

A quick scan of the [design guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545457.aspx) didn't find an official recommendation of order, but you can clearly see buttons are ordered from left to right by cancell-ness (i.e., the more you cancel the further to the right your button is... yes, maybe, no, never, icantbelieveyouaskedthat).

Answer (score 0):

It depends which platform background the user has, since dialogs and message boxes typically present buttons in a layout that conforms to the interface guidelines for that platform. Invariably, different platforms have different layouts for their dialogs.

I've accustomised already to the former, since I'm a Windows user and windows has that order.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think that depends on the button's alignment. If left aligned, I prefer the first, otherwise, the later.

In both cases the more used choice is a bit more visible.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with stg: it depends on the alignment for me. If the buttons are left aligned, the "accept" (or "submit") choice goes on the left. If the buttons are right aligned, that choice goes on the right.

And a personal pet peeve of mine: no matter how the buttons are aligned, or ordered, hitting the enter key should always invoke the "submit" action.

Answer (score 0):

As regards the [RESET] button, I think that the default form reset should never be used without a confirmation, especially in long forms...

Imagine the situation...a user is in a hurry and completing an online transaction, filling out personal details, credit card numbers, and tons of other stuff to needs checking, and when the user finishes, by mistake, he clicks the reset button instead of the submit...! believe me, that is a very annoying experience.

So I think, if you ever use a reset button, you should **first `confirm` with the user, and then reset the form**

Answer (score 0):

You can try different color schemes for [submit] and [reset]. In my form i prefer [submit] [reset] with different color and having highlighted [submit] button.