# Generic dialog with custom captions for buttons

Tags: delphi, dialog, customization, caption

I know this issue have been up since before (ex. [Best way to show customized message dialogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100073/what-is-the-best-way-in-delphi-to-show-customized-message-dialogs)), but I still don't find what I want.

I started like this:

```
class function TAttracsForm.MessageDlg(const aMsg: string; aDlgType: TMsgDlgType; Buttons: TMsgDlgButtons; aCaptions: array of String; aDefault: TMsgDlgBtn): TModalResult;
var
  vDlg: TForm;
  i: Integer; 
begin
  if aButtons.Count = aCaptions.Count then
  begin
    vDlg := CreateMessageDialog(aMsg, aDlgType, Buttons);
    try
      for i := 0 aCaptions.Count - 1 do
        TButton(vDlg.FindComponent(Buttons[i].Caption)).Caption := aCaptions[i]; 

      vDlg.Position := poDefaultPosOnly;
      Result := vDlg.ShowModal;
    finally
      vDlg.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

And the call would look like:

```
if (MessageDlg('Really quit application ?', mtWarning, 
       [mbNo, mbCancel, mbYes], {'No save', 'Cancel', 'Save'}) = mrYes) then
```

But the above code of course don't compile. I don't know how to get one item of an set in the loop and how to get the total count of it in the beginning.

Comment: Maybe you can use TTaskDialog or one of the pre-Vista capable emulations.

Comment: +1 I agree that the Vista task dialog is the way to go when it is available.

Comment: My application run only on XP and Server 2003 R2 so I cannot use TTaskDialog.

Comment: @Roland: There are emulations, e.g. [JSDialog](http://www.jed-software.com/jsd.htm), one from TMS, [SynTaskDialog](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/03/05/Open-Source-SynTaskDialog-unit-for-XP,Vista,Seven)

Comment: [Inofficial `TTaskDialog` documentation](http://specials.rejbrand.se/TTaskDialog/)

Comment: @Andreas: <OT>You could set HTML anchors in your inofficial docu and then directly link to, say, "Custom Buttons"</OT>

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you can use this code:

```
function MyMessageDlg(CONST Msg: string; DlgTypt: TmsgDlgType; button: TMsgDlgButtons;
  Caption: ARRAY OF string; dlgcaption: string): Integer;
var
  aMsgdlg: TForm;
  i: Integer;
  Dlgbutton: Tbutton;
  Captionindex: Integer;
begin
  aMsgdlg := createMessageDialog(Msg, DlgTypt, button);
  aMsgdlg.Caption := dlgcaption;
  aMsgdlg.BiDiMode := bdRightToLeft;
  Captionindex := 0;
  for i := 0 to aMsgdlg.componentcount - 1 Do
  begin
    if (aMsgdlg.components[i] is Tbutton) then
    Begin
      Dlgbutton := Tbutton(aMsgdlg.components[i]);
      if Captionindex <= High(Caption) then
        Dlgbutton.Caption := Caption[Captionindex];
      inc(Captionindex);
    end;
  end;
  Result := aMsgdlg.Showmodal;
end;
```

For example:

```
MyMessageDlg('Hello World!', mtInformation, [mbYes, mbNo],
      ['Yessss','Noooo'], 'New MessageDlg Box'):
```

Comment: Work perfectly but in example must use , and not ; for dividing parameters and you can check it with normal MessageDlg results. So use it as this way: if MyMessageDlg('Hello World!', mtInformation, [mbYes, mbNo],
      ['Yessss','Noooo'], 'New MessageDlg Box') = mrYes then Begin .... End

Comment: @Holmes For a solution with Firemonkey have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35232732/2306907).

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work in Lazarus 1.8.0.
The custom caption does not affect the actual button caption, ist just 'yes' and 'no.'

Comment: Why set it to `bdRightToLeft`? It ends up destroying the text.

Comment: @JerryDodge Because it was supposed to run for Right to Left languages like Persian ;) 
For Left to Right languages, you don't need.

Answer (score 8):

How about something like this:

```
type
  TButtonInfo = record
    MsgDlgBtn: TMsgDlgBtn;
    Caption: string;
  end;

function ButtonInfo(MsgDlgBtn: TMsgDlgBtn; const Caption: string): TButtonInfo;
begin
  Result.MsgDlgBtn := MsgDlgBtn;
  Result.Caption := Caption;
end;

const
  ModalResults: array[TMsgDlgBtn] of Integer = (
    mrYes, mrNo, mrOk, mrCancel, mrAbort, mrRetry, mrIgnore, mrAll, mrNoToAll,
    mrYesToAll, 0, mrClose);

function FindDialogButton(Form: TForm; MsgDlgBtn: TMsgDlgBtn): TButton;
var
  i: Integer;
  Component: TComponent;
begin
  for i := 0 to Form.ComponentCount-1 do begin
    Component := Form.Components[i];
    if Component is TButton then begin
      if TButton(Component).ModalResult=ModalResults[MsgDlgBtn] then begin
        Result := TButton(Component);
        exit;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  Result := nil;
end;

function MessageDlg(
  const aMsg: string;
  aDlgType: TMsgDlgType;
  const Buttons: array of TButtonInfo;
  aDefault: TMsgDlgBtn
): TModalResult;
var
  i: Integer;
  MsgDlgButtons: TMsgDlgButtons;
  vDlg: TForm;
begin
  MsgDlgButtons := [];
  for i := low(Buttons) to high(Buttons) do begin
    Assert(not (Buttons[i].MsgDlgBtn in MsgDlgButtons));//assert uniqueness
    Include(MsgDlgButtons, Buttons[i].MsgDlgBtn);
  end;
  vDlg := CreateMessageDialog(aMsg, aDlgType, MsgDlgButtons, aDefault);
  try
    for i := low(Buttons) to high(Buttons) do begin
      FindDialogButton(vDlg, Buttons[i].MsgDlgBtn).Caption := Buttons[i].Caption;
    end;
    vDlg.Position := poDefaultPosOnly;
    Result := vDlg.ShowModal;
  finally
    vDlg.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure Test;
begin
  MessageDlg(
    'Really quit application ?',
    mtWarning,
    [ButtonInfo(mbNo, 'Do&n''t save'), ButtonInfo(mbCancel, '&Cancel'), ButtonInfo(mbYes,'&Save')],
    mbYes
  );
end;
```

[image]

Comment: Why not? Is it because I used accelerator keys perhaps? Also, "This doesn't work" isn't a very good error report.....  ;-)

Comment: @David - that's the error message most of our users report!  LOL

Comment: I think you might not want `FindComponent(Buttons[i].Caption)`. It is pretty unlikely that the unmodified dialog has a control named `'Do&nt'' save'`.

Comment: It's a bit interesting that you get upvotes even though your code doesn't work! Clearly, people aren't actually trying the code before upvoting! Still, your code is *beautiful*, and deserves a lot of upvotes as soon as the bug is fixed.

Comment: @Andreas @Roland Code works now!! Pretty hacky, but there you go. Would be quite easy to roll your own Task Dialog type form.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks! Not sure I'd say beautiful though!!

Comment: @David: Interesting, your solution is *identical* to the one I just wrote, that is, using a conversion array between buttons and modal results.

Comment: @Andreas It's funny, I saw all the other issues with the code, but assumed the FindComponent stuff was fine since I never do stuff like that anyway!

Comment: David I tried the code and it doesn't work because of the reason Andreas said. FindComponent(Buttons[i].Caption) may be wrong. But I think the problem is solved anyway even if it isn't exactly as I want it. And the upvote is just for a good try for you David... :)

Comment: @Roland The code works perfectly. You are probably running the original version. I edited it yesterday and now it works. As you can see above, there is no call to FindComponent. This is your answer.

Comment: @ShahramBanazadeh What do you mean?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I can not see routine that sets default (selected ) button passed by last parameter(adefault) .not implemented ?

Comment: @Shahram How it is set? Again I don't know what you mean. Why don't you read the code and see how the parameter is used?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Because it is not used. I was wondering if I am missing some thing.
aDefault: TMsgDlgBtn is not used in body.

Comment: I see. I've fixed it now.

Comment: (Posted for [https://stackoverflow.com/users/6227080/nervouz](Nervouz) who can't comment himself.) Nice code @DavidHeffernan! It`s work for me. I can't anwer on your post. There are some way to make the length of buttons "customized" or "Justified"? Thank you!

Comment: @computer the question is about delphi

Comment: I wrote many custom dialog functions for personal use, but your approach was beautiful, thanks @DavidHeffernan

Answer (score 3):

I write this code: (I am from Croatia, so the texts are in Croatian)

```
function MojDijalog(const Msg, Capt: string; DlgType: TMsgDlgType; Buttons: TMsgDlgButtons;
  DefaultButton: TMsgDlgBtn): TModalResult;
var
  dlg : TForm;
begin
  dlg := CreateMessageDialog(Msg, DlgType, Buttons, DefaultButton) ;
  with dlg do begin
     Caption := Capt;
     FormStyle := fsStayOnTop;
     ( FindComponent( 'OK' ) as TButton ).Caption := 'U redu' ;
     ( FindComponent( 'Cancel' ) as TButton ).Caption := 'Odustani' ;
     ( FindComponent( 'Yes' ) as TButton ).Caption := 'Da' ;
     ( FindComponent( 'No' ) as TButton ).Caption := 'Ne' ;
      ( FindComponent( 'Help' ) as TButton ).Caption := 'Pomoć' ;
     ( FindComponent( 'Close' ) as TButton ).Caption := 'Zatvori' ;
     ( FindComponent( 'Ignore' ) as TButton ).Caption := 'Zanemari' ;
     ( FindComponent( 'Retry' ) as TButton ).Caption := 'Pokušaj ponovo' ;
     ( FindComponent( 'Abort' ) as TButton ).Caption := 'Prekini' ;
     ( FindComponent( 'All' ) as TButton ).Caption := 'Sve' ;
  end;
  Result := dlg.ShowModal;
end;
```

Example of use :

```
if MojDijalog('Obrisati zapis ?','Upit za brisanje',mtConfirmation,mbYesNo,mbNo) = mrNo then
    begin
         Abort;
    end;
```