# Change title in MessageDlgPos in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I try show a MessageDlgPos with a different title in Delphi , It has to be MessageDlgPos because I need to specify the position x and y

how I can change the title of a MessageDlgPos?

Comment: I asked only for MessageDlgPos , not for MessageDlg , it is not same

Comment: Which Delphi version? What exactly do you mean with "title", the caption of the form or the title (Vista+) in the client area above the message?

Comment: Please (why do I have to repeat), what do you mean with "title"? If you don't understand my question, say so. Don't hope it goes away ;)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have voted to reopen this question as there is a more simple solution than the referred to duplicate.

Comment: @FF2 `MessageDlgPos` is implemented by a call to `CreateMessageDialog`.

Comment: @TomBrunberg What is that?

Comment: @David TaskMessageDlgPosHelp()

Comment: @TomBrunberg That's a bit of a dicy one. Especially on XE2 I think. If you aren't themed, or on XP, I think the title will not find it's way to the dialog.

Comment: @David It exists in XE2. OS needs to be Vista or better AFAIK, availability on XP is unknowwn for me

Comment: @TomBrunberg I know it exists, but if themes are disabled for any reason, the Title is ignored. Look at the implementation.

Answer (score -1):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1100084/672), but modify this line:

```
dialog.Position := poScreenCenter;
```